What Does the Abarbanel Mean When He States That Samson's Relationship With Women Proves That They Were NOT Jewish Converts?
The Abarbanel disagrees with the Rambam/Ralbag/Chazal (Judges 13) and states:

ו ואין ראוי שנסתפק במה שאחז"ל (עיין רלב"ג) שהיה מגייר אותן ושהשיבן לדת ישראל, כי זה לא נזכר בכתוב, וגם ספורי הנשים ומעשיו עמהן ומעשיהן עמו לא יסבול שיאמר זה, It is not fitting for us to be satisfied with what Chazal say - that he (Samson) converted them (the women he encountered in his life) and returned them to the Jewish religion - because this is not mentioned in the narrative, and the stories with women and his actions with them, and them with him, make it untenable to say this (that they were Jewish converts) ...

What specifically does the Abarbanel mean? The fact that several betrayed Samson? His gaming/riddle with them? His taking a Zona/harlot? All of the above?

See Abarbanel on Shofetim 14:20, where she was married to Shimshon yet fell in love with / slept illicitly with one of his wedding companions. https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.14.20?lang=bi&with=Abarbanel&lang2=he

@ josh waxman I found this too in the Abarbanel - about how perfidious Delilah was to pretend that her questions about Samson's strength were coming from a place of love. Is that your sense too?
(יג) עד הנה התלת בי ותדבר אלי כזבים, רוצה לומר איני חוששה על זה ואיני מפצרת כבר בזה ענין כי אם לפי שהתלת בי ודברי עמי כזבים ולכן אשתדל על כרחך שתגיד לי האמת, וכל זה מעניני הנשים הזונות לבעליהן מרבות תלונות עמהם ותאמרו שהם מאהבה מסותרת

ספורי הנשים = the stories of the women. Yes, it means that the women were faithful to the philistines, not to him
